# Why the re is this mysterious character for space in Greek?

Tags: xetex, greek

I have the following tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} 
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\title{Tο μικρό γλυκό πρωτόκολλο WPA-PSK}
\date{}
\author{Τσακ Νόρις}

\begin{document}

   \maketitle

   \chapter{Επίθεση σε οικιακό δίκτυο Wi-Fi που χρησιμοποιεί WPA2-CCMP-PSK}
   \section{Εργαλεία Επίθεσης}
   Προκειμένου να εκτελεστεί η επίθεση, χρησιμοποιήσαμε το εργαλείο \texttt{airchack-ng} σε \texttt{Kubuntu Linux 16.04 lts}.　Λαλαλαλα θα τα σπάσω όλα.
\end{document}
```

And I noticed that there is some mysterious characters for space as you can see in image:
[image: Rendered Tex]

In my case is the character: [image: Weird Character]

I Use TexStudio on Ubuntu 16.04. If you want to check it out I recommend using [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eSw9HCVYUhapF0H5Ad2kBj50PHwLzbG6) link to download it.

Comment: with pretest TeXLive 2018 on Ubuntu 16.04 I do not get the mysterious character after copying pasting the code in an Emacs buffer and compiling from there.

Comment: but log contains ``Missing character: There is no 　 in font Linux Libertine O/OT:script=grek;langu``  where the character is Unicode IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE, ``#xE3 #x80 #x80 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)`` U+3000

Comment: the big space character is in input... just delete it (after the end of sentence mark)...

Comment: That's the /.notdef character. You get it (but not with every font) if you use a glyph that isn't in the font. Beside this: You are overdoing with xltxtra, fontspec, libertine, xunicode. Only libertine should be enough.

Comment: So if I use a different font I can display it correctly right?

Comment: perhaps you have an editor which converts two spaces ending a sentence into a Unicode U+3000 wide space ? or you copied pasted the input from some other source ?

Comment: No perhaps it is mistyped from the Japaneese language I have set up. I wonder if there is a way to convert it into greek space.

Comment: you mean TeXStudio is configured for Japanese? There is no Japanese in this document. (I mean apart this CJK wide space...)

Comment: I have Japaneese Language set up and during the language change I mistype the Japaneese white space instead of the Greek one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a spurious space U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE between the period after `lts}` and `Λαλαλαλα`.

If I paste the text in https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ and click “Convert”, the box HTML/XML shows

```
\texttt{Kubuntu Linux 16.04 lts}.&#x3000;Λαλαλαλα
```

You should remove the offending character or do

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^^^3000}{ }
```

(but getting rid of the character is better).

By the way, you should no longer load `xltxtra` and `xunicode`.